# support ranges and boolean term condition in searchkick rails 5?

Tags: searchkick, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm using Searchkick in my Rails 5 application and I'm trying to support ranges and boolean term condition in app.

My range query with where like:

```
Model.search '*', where: { _or: [ { age_years: { gte: "5", lte: "7" } } ] }
```

But I got an error as below:

```
"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Cannot search on field [age_years] since it is not indexed."}
```

Also I've tried with aggs query like:

```
options = {:aggs=>{:age_years=>{:ranges=>[{:from=>7, :to=> 12}]}}} Model.search("*", options)
```

But I got an error as below:

```
{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [age_years] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}
```

My term query like:

```
Model.search "*", where: {lc_vet_care: true}
```

But I got not indexed error same like range where query error.

how can I fix this with searchkick?

Comment: `Cannot search on field [age_years] since it is not indexed.` you haven't index your records yet.. have you tried running `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Model`

Comment: Yes, I have tried `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Model` but didn't worked

Comment: OK, are you sure your `model` name is `Model` and not something else ex: `User or Post`

Comment: My model name is not `Model` it's `Pet`.

Comment: Then the command you should be running is `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Pet`

Comment: If it still throws an error while reindex, then please add error to the question.